# Java 6 or 7 is required error while creating Glassfish server in Oracle package for Eclipse

Tags: glassfish-3

I am Creating Glassfish server in Oracle package for Eclipse.
Current java version is 1.8 but still getting error "Java 6 or 7 is required"

Error snippet below

Comment: Java8 is not java6 or 7

Comment: Where's the error snippet? What Glassfish version you're using? Glassfish 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glassfish 3 won't work with Java 8.

If you want to use Java 8, try Glassfish 4.+